# Using KeychainAccess to remove all items

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I'm using a very basic Swift library called [KeychainAccess](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess) to handle the gets and sets for keychain keys within my app.

I am trying to remove all keychain items on the first run of my app. All my code works without a problem, besides the removing of all items. My first attempt was to run through each key and remove it individually, like so:

```
var keychain: Keychain!
if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("FirstRun") == nil) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue("1strun", forKey: "FirstRun")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

    //Reset the keychain by looping through all and removing
    let allItems = keychain.allItems()
    for item in allItems {
        do {
            try keychain.remove(item["key"] as! String)
        } catch let error {
            print("error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Although, when attempting to get `keychain.allItems()`, I get an error of: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

So I dug more into the [`Keychain.swift`](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess/blob/master/Lib/KeychainAccess/Keychain.swift) file and found a function called `removeAll()`. So I attempted to use that, like so:

```
do {
    try keychain.removeAll()
} catch let error {
    print("error: \(error)")
}
```

Yet I received the same error as above.

I believe the problem is because the keychain for my app is already empty.

Comment: Try `if let allItems = keychain.allItems()` and wrap your `for` loop in that binding.  If it cannot bind the logic will be skipped.

Comment: @Joe - That gives an error inside xcode of `Initalizer for conditional binding must have Option type, not '[[String : AnyObject]]'`

Comment: understood; is it possible then that either `keychain` is an optional itself (you said that when you tried to use both `allItems` or `removeAll` you received the error), _or_, some other statement is the actual unwrapping, _or_ the error is within the Keychain code itself.

Comment: @Fizzix Neither `keychain.allItems()` nor `keychain.removeAll()` do force unwrap optional velue. Can you make sure where the error occurred? Can you show more detail code?

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi - Just ran some tests, and the error happens on the line `try keychain.removeAll()`. See this screenshot - https://postimg.org/image/brsa3391j/

Comment: @Fizzix It seems the `keychain` variable is nil. Where did you create keychain instance?

Comment: You can see that I set it inside my AppDelegate, refer to previous comment where I posted a screenshot.

Comment: @Fizzix Of course I saw the screenshot. You just declare member variable `var keychain: Keychain!`, but you didn't set any instance...

Comment: @Fizzix Can you tell me what does it print inserting `print(keychain)` before `keychain.allItems()`?

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi - Doing `print(keychain)` also gives the same error. Maybe it's not allowed to be called inside `AppDelegate`? I have keychain items being saved and retrieved perfectly inside my `ViewController`.

Comment: @Fizzix You must create `Keychain` instance before use it. That's all. Change `var keychain: Keychain!` to `let keychain = Keychain()` or insert `keychain = Keychain()` before using it. This has nothing to do with the keychain. It is the basis of programming.

Comment: The Casey's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

it's a bit of a guessing game until you post the declaration of `keychain`, however i'd guess from the error you have it declared like this:

```
var keychain: Keychain!
```

if so, the error is trying to tell you that `keychain` is nil

Answer (score 0):

If someone simply wants keychain to remove everything and start from zero,
this is a simple way:

```
let key = "somekey"
let keychain = Keychain(service: key)


let keys = keychain.allKeys()
for key in keys {
    print("key: \(key)")
    do {
        try keychain.remove(key)
    } catch let error {
        print("error: \(error)")
    }
}
```